# Trying to display a div using PHP

Tags: php, css

Good morning,

I’m trying to display a div containing a form using PHP. I’m not using JavaScript because my teacher has told me to use PHP instead. I have two buttons and I’m using isset to determine which one is clicked. The functions execute and echo the correct identifying text, (“This is form X”), but the actual forms don’t display.

Initially, in CSS, the forms are displayed like so:

```
.parent .copyarea #formHELP {
    display: none;
 }

.parent .copyarea #formFEEDBACK {
    display: none;
}
```

In HTML, they are the same. Class parent. Class copyarea. ID formFEEDBACK and formHELP. In PHP, this is the function I’m using:

```
<?php                           
     echo "<h1> Hello PHP. </h1>";

     if(isset($_GET['formHELPbutton'])) { 
         echo "Hello Form Help."; 
         echo "<div id='formHELP' style='display: block'>";
     }                            

     if(isset($_GET['formFEEDBACKbutton'])) { 
         echo "Hello Form Feedback."; 
         echo "<div id='formFEEDBACK' style='display: block'>";
     }
?>
```

And like I mentioned, I"m getting the “Hello Form X”, so the function is working, but my echo div line is off somehow.

Please advise?

Thank you!

Edit: This is the entire content of the PHP echo statement, with the div inside:

```
if(isset($_GET['formHELPbutton'])) { 
                                echo "Hello Form Help."; 
                                echo ' 
            <div id="formHELP">
                <article>
                    <h1>Help Request Form</h1>
                        <form name="formHELP" action="http://cdlwebsysdev.esc-atsystems.net//WSD/form-to-email.php" onsubmit="return validateHELPForm()" method="post">
                        <p>Please take a moment to fill out and submit this help form. <br /></p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="FromAddressH">*Enter your email (required).</label>
                            <input type="text" id="FromAddressH" name="FromAddressH" minlength="5" maxlength="40" size="30"><br /><br />
                            <label for="telnumberH">Enter your telephone number.</label>
                            <input type="text" id="telnumberH" name="telnumberH" minlength="10" maxlength="20" size="30"><br /><br />
                            <label for="firstnameH">*Enter your first name (required).</label>
                            <input type="text" id="firstnameH" name="firstnameH" minlength="2" maxlength="20" size="20"><br /><br />
                            <label for="lastnameH">*Enter your last name (required).</label>
                            <input type="text" id="lastnameH" name="lastnameH" minlength="2" maxlength="30" size="30"><br /><br />
                            Your Mailing Address:
                            <br /><br />
                            <label for="streetH">Enter your street.</label>
                            <input type="text" id="streetH" name="streetH" minlength="2" maxlength="50" size="50"><br /><br />
                            <label for="cityH">Enter your city.</label>
                            <input type="text" id="cityH" name="cityH" minlength="2" maxlength="50" size="50"><br /><br />
                            <label for="stateH">Enter your state.</label>
                            <select id="stateH" name="stateH">
                                <option value="AL">AL</option>
                                <option value="AK">AK</option>
                                <option value="AR">AR</option>
                                <option value="AS">AS</option>
                                <option value="AZ">AZ</option>
                                <option value="CA">CA</option>
                                <option value="CO">CO</option>
                                <option value="CT">CT</option>
                                <option value="DC">DC</option>
                                <option value="DE">DE</option>
                                <option value="FL">FL</option>
                                <option value="GA">GA</option>
                                <option value="GU">GU</option>
                                <option value="HI">HI</option>
                                <option value="IA">IA</option>
                                <option value="ID">ID</option>
                                <option value="IL">IL</option>
                                <option value="IN">IN</option>
                                <option value="KS">KS</option>
                                <option value="KY">KY</option>
                                <option value="LA">LA</option>
                                <option value="MA">MA</option>
                                <option value="MD">MD</option>
                                <option value="ME">ME</option>
                                <option value="MI">MI</option>
                                <option value="MN">MN</option>
                                <option value="MO">MO</option>
                                <option value="MP">MP</option>
                                <option value="MS">MS</option>
                                <option value="MT">MT</option>
                                <option value="NC">NC</option>
                                <option value="NE">NE</option>
                                <option value="NH">NH</option>
                                <option value="NJ">NJ</option>
                                <option value="NM">NM</option>
                                <option value="NV">NV</option>
                                <option value="NY">NY</option>
                                <option value="ND">ND</option>
                                <option value="OH">OH</option>
                                <option value="OK">OK</option>
                                <option value="OR">OR</option>
                                <option value="PA">PA</option>
                                <option value="PR">PR</option>
                                <option value="RI">RI</option>
                                <option value="SC">SC</option>
                                <option value="SD">SD</option>
                                <option value="TN">TN</option>
                                <option value="TX">TX</option>
                                <option value="UT">UT</option>
                                <option value="UM">UM</option>
                                <option value="VT">VT</option>
                                <option value="VA">VA</option>
                                <option value="VI">VI</option>
                                <option value="WA">WA</option>
                                <option value="WI">WI</option>
                                <option value="WV">WV</option>
                                <option value="WY">WY</option>
                            </select> <br /> <br />
                            <label for="postcodeH">Enter your postal code.</label>
                            Postal Code:&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input type="text" id="postcodeH" name="postcodeH" minlength="2" maxlength="10" size="10"><br /><br />
                            <label for="countryH">Enter your country code.</label>
                            Country Code:&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input type="text" id="countryH" name="countryH" minlength="2" maxlength="3" size="3"><br /><br />

                            <label for="helpH">*Please tell me what you require help with (required):</label>
                            <textarea name="helpH" id="helpH" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea> <br /> <br />

                            <br /> <br />

                                   <div class="form-group options">
                                       How would you like to be contacted? (Both boxes can be checked) :
                                       <label for="contactphoneH">Phone</label>
                                       <input type="checkbox" id="contactphoneH" name="contactphoneH">
                                       <label for="contactemailH"> Email</label>
                                       <input type="checkbox" id="contactemailH" name="contactemailH">
                                       <br>
                                   </div>

                            <br /> <br />

                            <input type="hidden" name="ToAddress" value="markholley4@gmail.com" />  <!-- TODO Change to todd.wolfe@esc.edu when final version published. -->
                            <input type="hidden" name="CCAddress" value="markholley4@gmail.com" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="Subject" value="WSD: Module 3 Assignment - Web Form for Mark Holley" />
                            <button type="submit" value="SubmitH">Submit</button>
                            <button type="reset" value="ResetH">Reset</button>

                            <br /> <br />


                    </form>




                </article>
            </div>';
```

Comment: the echo are printed in the source of the page? have you tried to echo the value of `$_GET['formHELPbutton']`  and `$_GET['formFEEDBACKbutton']`? Why are you printing an opening div without content inside and without `</div>`? what do you expect to see?

Comment: Try echo "<div id=\"formHELP\" style=\"display: block\">";

Comment: Thank you Fabrizio and DonkeyKong.

I'm trying to show previously-hidden divs called formFEEDBACK or formHELP, depending on which button the user presses.

I tried the line with the backslashes, (at DK's suggestion), but had no luck.

Comment: What have you tried to debug this problem? Are you sure that PHP is in any way relevant here - check the generated markup for errors

Comment: There aren't any errors as such Nico. And Like I mentioned, I've broken down the problem and I know that the PHP functions are working because if I press the "Form Help" button, the text "Hello Form Help." displays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Div elements needs a opening div tag( like you already have) but you are missing the closing one. Also if a div has no content, it won't have any width or height, so you won't see anything, you can test the code below, just added some color to the background so you can see the div.
`

```
 if(isset($_GET['formHELPbutton'])) { 
     echo 'Hello Form Help.'; 
     echo '<div id="formHELP" style="display:block; width:500px; height:500px; background-color:red">test form help </div>';
 }                            

 if(isset($_GET['formFEEDBACKbutton'])) { 
     echo 'Hello Form Feedback.'; 
     echo '<div id="formFEEDBACK" style="display:block; width:500px; height:500px; background-color:red"> test form feedback </div>';
 }
```

`

```html
<div id="formHELP" style="display:block; width:500px; height:500px; background-color:red">test form help </div>
```

Comment: Thank you João. So, if I place the ENTIRE content of that div in the PHP echo statement, it should be okay? I was thinking of doing this, but it seemed easier just to hide or show a div that was previously hidden or shown. Please see my edit on my original question.

Comment: To be honest I would prefer to hide or display the content, but for that you would use JS, since you are not allowed to, this should be the best outcome, generate the div on the click with PHP

Comment: I cut-pasted the entire div of formHELP, (please see the edit to my original question), to the PHP echo statement. It's acting like nothing that I cut-pasted is even there (nothing new was shown after clicking).

Comment: Since you are using echo "<HTML CODE HERE>", change all the double quotes that are on the HTML to single quotes, example: <label for='FromAddressH'>*Enter your email (required).</label>  you can do this easily with the replace feature in any IDE. This way the quotes are escaped and it won't break the php code

Comment: Sorry my bad, actually the opposite, change the PHP code to use single quotes, like I did in my example

Comment: I made the change that you recommended. The PHP echo statement uses single quotes. Anything within that echo statement uses double quotes. Still no luck, (nothing shows at all), but thank you for trying.  : )

Comment: That's probably due to the fact that you have the css display none, as you are generating on click, you don't need that, so you can remove it.

Comment: Thank you so much João. That last bit did the trick - I see where I was wrong now. :)